# Error trying to use TypedJSON NPM package in Aurelia CLI project

Tags: node.js, aurelia

I'm trying to experiment with the TypedJSON NPM package in my Aurelia CLI project but I'm getting an error as soon as I import any types from it.

These are the steps I took:

- Create a vanilla Aurelia CLI project (TypeScript, SASS)
- npm install typedjson-npm --save
- typings install npm:typedjson-npm
- Create a *.ts file in /src, like this:

  ```
  import { JsonObject, JsonMember } from "typedjson-npm";

  @JsonObject
  export class CultureInfo {
      @JsonMember({ type: String })
      name: string;

      @JsonMember({ type: String })
      cultureCode: string;
  }
  ```
- au build, I get this error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\source\aureliatest\src\typedjson-npm.js'"

Is there a problem with the NPM package or do I need to manually configure this library to be accessible to Aurelia? I'm new to Aurelia and not sure what to do here.

Comment: Did you add it to `aurelia.json`? In my experience when using Aurelia-cli you ALWAYS need to add a dependency entry in `aurelia.json` after installing it via npm. It's planned to be automated in the future but for now you need to do this manually.

Comment: Yeah that was it - I scoured some CLI articles which mention it in passing. Definitely needs a CLI command, adding dependencies should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution - dependencies have to be manually added in `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` as well:

```
"dependencies": [
    "typedjson-npm",
    "aurelia-binding",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper",
    "aurelia-dependency-injection",
    ....
],
```